# Can I implement custom token generation (fully customized) API Token in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to implement a custom code for token generation or you can think of removing OAuth2 from the WSO2 implementation and incorporating my specific APIs for token management. Is this possible? If yes, then please guide me how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to customize it fully,  It means that you need to completely remove the OAuth2. There there is no worth of it. But; if you just need to customize some behaviors of the OAuth2,  It can be done easily.  There are several extension points for it.  One main extension is that customization of OAuth2 grant types.  You can find details from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/01/20/custom-grant-type-with-oauth/) and some sample for it.  It may helps to do some major customization of the OAuth2 flow. Hope it would help for you.

Comment: Hi Asela -  - with grant type I believe I still need to provide OAuth2 token and  I want to provide a different mechanism for that. Specially we have custom key generation tool which I want to use for authentication. Please let me whether I can use our own logic to create, display and use our authentication key

Comment: You can customize the access token.   When customizing the grant type,  you can use custom key generation tool to  create the access token.

Answer (score 0):

When you send an API request to the backend, you pass a token in the Authorization header of the request.  The API Gateway uses this token to authorize access, and then drops it from the outgoing message.  If you wish to use a different (or a custom generated) authorization token than the application generated access token, you can use it as a token exchange mechanism in mediation logic of the API. In this tutorial, we explain how to pass a custom authorization token that is different to the authorization token generated for the application.

1. Add the following sequence content in to a file and save it as XML file.

2. Log in to the API Publisher, create a new REST API
3. Navigate to the Runtime Configurations tab, enable the Message Mediation in Request flow. Engage the In sequence that you created earlier and click Save .
4. If the API is not in PUBLISHED state, go to Lifecycle tab, click REDPLOY to re-publish the API.
5. Go Developer Portal, subscribe and obtain a token to invoke the published API.
6. Install any REST client in your machine. We use cURL here.
7. Go to the command line, and invoke the API using the following cURL command.
   In this command, you pass the token that the backend expects, i.e., 1234, in the Custom header with the authorization token that the system generates in the Authorization header.

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer " -H "Custom: Bearer 1234"

**NOTE**
 is the token that you got in step 20.
 appears on the API's Overview page in the API Developer Portal. Copy the HTTP endpoint. If you select the HTTPs endpoint, be sure to run the cURL command with the -k option.

8. Note the response that you get in the command line. According to the sample backend used in this tutorial, you get the response as "Request Received."

FOR MORE EXPLANATION, PLEASE VISIT THIS LINK

[LINK] : https://medium.com/@PrakhashS/passing-access-token-to-oauth2-protected-backends-wso2-api-manager-7d0671a0afca